# Fix(Gal($\bar{F}/F)) = F$ when $\bar{F}$ is separable over $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here $\bar{F}$ is an algebraic closure of $F$. 
I really don't know how to approach this problem since we can't use that being Galois is equivalent to being normal and separable since the extension is not given to be finite.  I'm guessing this means I have to directly use automorphisms, but I'm not sure if that is right or even how to go about doing such a thing.  Do I need to show that $F \subset \bar{F}$ is Galois or can I assume it since the question asks for Fix(Gal$(\bar{F}/F$))?

Comment: What's your definition of Fix?

Comment: $Fix(G \acts X) = {x \in X: gx =x \forall g \in G}$

Comment: Hint: if $f \in F[t]$ is an irreducible polynomial, and $\alpha$ and $\beta \in \overline{F}$ are roots of $f$, then the $F$-isomorphism of fields $F(\alpha) \rightarrow F(\beta)$ extends to an element of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{F}/F)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $F \subseteq Fix(Gal(\bar{F}/F))$ by definition. So, show that for any $x\in \bar{F}\backslash F$, there is an automorphism fixing $F$ that does not fix $x$.

Comment: Thank you, but I am so confused about this question I don't fully understand what you mean.  I get that you are telling me to prove $Fix(Gal(\bar{F}/F) \subset F$, but I don't see how taking $x \in \bar{F}\F$ and finding an automorphism that fixes F but doesn't fix F accomplishes this.  I think I'm having trouble understanding what fixing means.  Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: $Fix(Gal(K/F))=\{k\in K| \forall \sigma \in Gal(K/F), \sigma(k)=k\}$

Comment: The fixed subfield is the subfield of elements that are fixed by all of the automorphisms in the Galois group. So, if there is just one automorphism that does not fix a given element, then that element is not in the fixed subfield. (By the way, use \backslash to type "\" in LaTeX)

Comment: Ok so the set of all elements of K such that every automorphism in the Galois group is the identity.  And showing that for any x there is an automorphism that fixes $F$ but doesn't fix $x$ makes sense to me now as a method of approaching this (I think I'm just extra tired from all the heat today).  So can I just create a function f where f(u) = u for all u in F, but f(u)= 1 for all u outside of F or something similar?

Comment: It has to be more complicated than that since what you said would not be in the Galois group. You probably want a different automorphism for each $x$. I think the comment by D_S will give you a way to do that.